# How to fetch balances of all assets/tokens from a Temple Wallet in a React app?

Tags: blockchain

I'm building a React application that integrates with the Temple Wallet, a popular Tezos wallet. I would like to fetch the balances of all assets or tokens held in the wallet programmatically within my React app.

I have already integrated the Temple Wallet into my app using the **@temple-wallet/dapp**
and **@taquito** packages, and the user can successfully connect their wallet and interact with the Tezos blockchain. I can also fetch the Tezos balance correctly using the following code:

```js
const tezos = new TezosToolkit("https://rpc.tzkt.io/ghostnet");
const balance = (await tezos.rpc.getBalance(walletAddress))?.toNumber()
```

However, I couldn't find any clear documentation or examples on how to fetch the balances of all other assets or tokens from the connected Temple Wallet (like the LYZI ones). I would like to display the asset balances in my app's UI.

Is there a way to achieve this using the Temple Wallet API or any other related libraries? Could someone provide an example or point me in the right direction to fetch the balances of all assets or tokens from a connected Temple Wallet within a React app?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can query all token balances for a particular account using TzKT API: https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/Tokens_GetTokenBalances

Here is how you can do that using TS SDK:

```js
import { tokensGetTokenBalances } from '@tzkt/sdk-api'

const account = 'tz1SLgrDBpFWjGCnCwyNpCpQC1v8v2N8M2Ks'
const limit = 10000
const offset = 0

const r = await tokensGetTokenBalances({
  account: {
    eq: account
  },
  balance: {
    ne: 0
  },
  limit,
  offset,
})
```

Note that there is a maximum page size (10000) so you need to iterate using offset/limit fields in case there are more than 10k tokens owned by a particular account.